# Postgres while insert from md5(variable) it inserts column name not column values

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

below is my postgres procedure

```
create or replace procedure ds_rs.test_ad () as $$
declare
i integer;
v_command text;
rcd record;
v_count text; v_pk_1 text; v_pk_2 text;
v_account_id varchar(100);
v_query text;
begin
for rcd in ( select t.table_name as object_name, a.table_schema, a.table_name from TLDEPLOY.TABLES_TO_VERIFY t
left join information_schema.tables a on concat
(COALESCE(a.table_schema, ''),'.',COALESCE(a.table_name, '')) = t.table_name order by t.table_name) loop
select count(*), max(column_name), min(column_name) into v_count, v_pk_1, v_pk_2 
from information_schema.table_constraints c 
join  information_schema.columns cl on cl.table_name =c.table_name 
where c.constraint_type ='PRIMARY KEY'
and c.table_name =rcd.table_name 
and c.TABLE_SCHEMA=rcd.table_schema   
and cl.ordinal_position =1
and cl.TABLE_SCHEMA=rcd.table_schema   ;
v_command :=('insert into ds_rs.test_table (pk_1,pk_2) select '||v_pk_1||' , '||md5(v_pk_2::text)||' from ds_rs.account');
execute v_command; 
end loop;
end; $$
language plpgsql;
```

while insert into table this query -> md5(v_pk_2::text) -> hash column name and inserts - i want column values to hash and insert

when used as normal - select md5(account_id::text) from account it gives correct value - but when passed as variable it inserts column name not column data

Comment: You need to spend some time here [Dynamic Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)

Comment: Take a look at your "select count(*), max(column_name), min(column_name) into v_count, v_pk_1, v_pk_2 " statement and make sure that the results being inserted into v_pk_2 are what you expect. As far as the actual md5(v_pk_2) function, you shouldn't need to cast it to text (::text) since the variable is already defined as text.